# Is there any maximum limit with mysql Group concat?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

Below is my query to get the records from table with group concat.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('''', order_number, '''' )) as order_number FROM edi_order_response where order_status = 'DELIVERED_INTIME' AND  DATE(`arul_timestamp`) BETWEEN '2018-08-21' AND '2018-08-22'
```

From the above query I am getting 93 records and one with unterminated record with single quote like below

```
'78E4PLMF','7TQ223UD','8FKC5B2F',......,'89KB6MRR','
```

But when I see in related table with the above date range there are nearly 330 records. So is there any way to get all the records based on the given date range? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To my way of thinking, GROUP_CONCAT serves almost no useful purpose, so my answer would be: don't bother with the GROUP_CONCAT!

Comment: Incidentally, `arul_timestamp BETWEEN '2018-08-21 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-22 23:59:59'` will be faster by orders of magnitude

Comment: If you cannot change your system settings then you cannot use group_concat where result would be > than the default maximum. You may need to present the result set in a different way or let whatever your presentation tool is do the job.

Comment: @strawberry Even better would be `arul_timestamp >= '2018-02-21' AND arul_timestamp < '2018-08-23'`

Comment: @P.Salmon, thanks for your suggestion. I have fixed this by using PHP

Comment: @MatBailie Would it? I'm not sure that it makes any difference as far as perfomance goes !?!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It is controlled by the setting `group_concat_max_len` and the default is 1024.

You can read about it in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

You can also set the value to a higher value:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = <some larger value>
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this from query? Becuase we don't have  access to ini files.

Comment: @user3408779 . . . You can set it at the session level.  For instance:  http://rextester.com/EFKOT50079.

Answer (score 1):

By Default it controlled by `group_contact_max_len` and having max length of `1024 characters`

Well you can change this to get more data like:

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = value_numeric;
```

value_numeric must be > `1024`; by default the `group_concat_max_len` value is `1024`.

Change in your mysql .ini file and restart your server.

If you don't have acess to server then you can achieve this by setting temporary session scope like

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
select group_concat(column) from table group by column
```

But it's gonna only work in this session only. For different session you have to set it again.